# Maximal continuous area of 0 bits inside matrix

Tags: matrices, geometry, pattern-recognition

I have a matrix of 1s and 0s and am trying to find the largest continuous polygon possible of 0s, See the attached picture as an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KBt9.jpg).
I'm looking for an algorithmic solution.

Any hints towards research paper of stuff like that are appreciated.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a graph with one node per matrix entry with value 0 and an edge for each pair of such entries that are adjacent.  Now find the *connected components* of this graph and take the largest one.

Comment: Or treat this as an image and use off-the-shelf region-finding algorithms.

Comment: "connected components" thanks a lot that's exactly what I need.